# Error while tying to run instruments with Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, xcode-instruments, xcode15

I'm trying to run instruments with Xcode 15, and all the instruments give the same error when I tap on the record button. I get the error in both cases while connecting to a physical device (iPad 16.1.1) and also connecting to a simulator (iPhone 17.0 Rosetta)

I do not see this issue with previous Xcode versions. I'm seeing this issue for the first time, and I could not find any resources that explains more about this error.

Not sure what details I could add that helps understand the problem better. The project has all the settings turned ON to make it eligible for debugging.

Note: Our project can only run with rosetta enabled simulators and on physical devices on Xcode 15. Even we had to enable rosetta on our M1 Macs with previous Xcode versions.

[image]
[image]

- M1 Pro chip
- OS version: Ventura 13.6
- Instruments version: 15.0
- Xcode version: 15.0

I will try with 15.0.1 Xcode version and update this question with more findings.

[image]

Comment: "Note: Our project can only run with rosetta enabled" Can you explain what that means? Using Xcode under Rosetta is no longer supported and shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I added new images to the questions, our current setup can only run on rosetta simulators, and physical devices. Our code is not yet supporting to run on simulators without rosetta enabled.

Comment: "our current setup can only run on rosetta simulators" Well, you need to fix that. You cannot use Xcode under Rosetta.

Comment: understood, we will consider it as higher priority if this issue needs to be resolved.I will update the question with more findings.

Comment: Here's the relevant tech note from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon

Comment: @matt appreciate the link